# Javascript coding challenge

Tags: javascript

I was given this question by a prospective client to solve and I wasn't able to on time, only the `makeSFns` function can be altered and as I was altering to give specific square values to match the `square` function (based on position in `arr`) I kept getting the error of `funcs[i] is not a function` which is weird because the square function its being compared to is returning a `number`, how does something that's expecting a function match a number?

```js
//Task: fix makeSFns function to show correct answer
var arr = [ Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random() ];
var square = function (x) { return x * x; };

function makeSFns(arr, square) {
    var fns = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        fns.push(function() {
            return square(arr[i]);
        });
    }
    return fns;
}

var funcs = makeSFns(arr, square);

isEqual = true;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (funcs[i]() !== square(arr[i])) {
        isEqual = false;
        console.log('wrong answer');
        break;
    }
}
if (isEqual) console.log('correct answer');
```

Some asking how I got the error, I tried finding a way to get position in `arr` and then returning

```
var position = 0; //outside the function

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    return square(arr[i]);             //replacing the push function
    position + 1; 
 }
```

Comment: My first guess is that `funcs` ended up being empty, so `funcs[i]` was `undefined`, which is not a function.

Comment: `I kept getting the error` ... run your snippet ... no such error ... the code you posted in the question is obviously **not** the code that produces the error ... as an aside ... `var i` -> `let i`

Comment: Show us *how* you altered the code so that it threw `funcs[i] is not a function`.

Comment: @Olli is there any reason for passing _function(){return square(x);}_ in push?

Comment: @JaromandaX, Bergi Updated, Yajiv that's how I got the question

Comment: oh, lol, you decided not to have any functions, and return after one iteration - no wonder funcs[i] isn't a function - you made `makeSFns` return the square of the first item ... i.e. `makeSFns` returns a single `Number`

Comment: wrong, that 2nd loop breaks after the first, and only checks if 1st is correct answer, but the 1st loop does contain functions.

Comment: wrong ... the `return square(arr[i])` is, as noted `//replacing the push function` - so not sure why you think the first loop would contain functions if he's got rid of replacing the `push`

Comment: @Olli - the challenge was to `fix makeSFns` - the fact that you tried adding something `outside the function` was your first mistake - your second mistake was a `return` inside a for loop. I'm intrigued that `a prospective client` would issue such a challenge. Most prospective clients know nothing about programming. Are you sure you didn't mean `a prospective employer`

Comment: Client/employer (a contract), I bid for contracts from time to time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a classic, since the `push` function is called after the loop, it's referencing the last known `i`, it is not correctly captured.

```js
//Task: fix makeSFns function to show correct answer
var arr = [ Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random() ];
var square = function (x) { return x * x; };

function makeSFns(arr, square) {
    var fns = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        (function(n) {
          fns.push(function() {
            return square(arr[n]);
          });
        })(i);
    }
    return fns;
}

var funcs = makeSFns(arr, square);

isEqual = true;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (funcs[i]() !== square(arr[i])) {
        isEqual = false;
        alert('wrong answer');
        break;
    }
}
if (isEqual) alert('correct answer');
```

More on the subject:

- [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1048572)
- http://www.datchley.name/loop-variable-gotcha/

Edit: [an interesting tranformation done by TypeScript when using the `let` keyword](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=for%20(let%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20arr.length%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fns.push(function()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20square(arr%5Bi%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%7D):

TS

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    fns.push(function() {
        return square(arr[i]);
    });
}
```

JS

```
var _loop_1 = function (i) {
    fns.push(function () {
        return square(arr[i]);
    });
};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    _loop_1(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are passing arr[i] into square function inside makeSFns but this value lost as it is not a true closure.

```js
//Task: fix makeSFns function to show correct answer
var arr = [ Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random() ];
var square = function (x) { return x * x; };

function makeSFns(arr, square) {
  return arr.map((num, i)=>()=>{
    return square(arr[i])
  });
}

var funcs = makeSFns(arr, square);

isEqual = true;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (funcs[i]() !== square(arr[i])) {
        isEqual = false;
        console.log('wrong answer');
        break;
    }
}
if (isEqual) console.log('correct answer');
```

Comment: it shows the inputs which are random numbers between 0 and 1, and then it shows the outputs, which are the squared version. 0.5*0.5 is 0.25 if you didn't know.

Comment: plus that's not the question, it doesn't matter it doesn't alert "correct answer"

Comment: but his question was why his function was not being called inside the second loop, and it was being called it was just that the value wasn't being passed to it. the comment is irrelevant, and he can easily put it in himself, since he wrote that code. unecessary

Comment: here you go, pedantic person

Comment: check the definition of pedantic

Comment: you do realise you've changed HOW the funcs are called ... from `funcs[i]()` to `funcs[i](arr[i])` ... i.e. you failed the test, because the challenge is to `fix makeSFns` ... not the surrounding code - thanks for playing though, and thanks for the attitude

Comment: hey you said something relevant ;)

Comment: I'm always relevant - just some people don't understand straight away

Answer (score 0):

It is because the array's reference is not available to the function being pushed into fns array, a classic javascript scenario.

```js
//Task: fix makeSFns function to show correct answer
//Task: fix makeSFns function to show correct answer
var arr = [ Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random() ];
var square = function (x) { return x * x; };

function makeSFns(arr, square) {
    var fns = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let myFn = function(myInput) {
            return square(myInput); 
        };
        fns.push(myFn.bind(null,arr[i]));
    }
    return fns;
}

var funcs = makeSFns(arr, square);

isEqual = true;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (funcs[i]() !== square(arr[i])) {
        isEqual = false;
        console.log('wrong answer');
        break;
    }
}
if (isEqual) console.log('correct answer');
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a solution to this that requires changing one keyword only:

```
  function makeSFns(arr, square) {
    var fns = [];
-    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
+    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       fns.push(function() {
         return square(arr[i]);
       });
     }
    return fns;
  }
```

Using `let` changes the scope of `i` and makes it behave like a separate closure.  Each iteration in the `for` loop will have it's own instance of `i`.